# GStreamer: cannot link elements in `CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open` running OpenCV C++ application

Tags: opencv, exception, gstreamer, odroid

I am trying to run an OpenCV program that opens a USB cam and streams the video.

The program compiles but when I run it I get the following GStreamer exception (which seems unrelated to OpenCV or the C++ source code):

```
(TLD:5263): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot link elements
) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/odroid/Desktop/middleware/CppLibs/opencv-2.4.13.6/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1464
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/odroid/Desktop/middleware/CppLibs/opencv-2.4.13.6/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1464: error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot link elements
 in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
```

I am running on odroid.

Have anybody had the same problem?

I was thinking it is a package dependency problem but I have installed `xorg` `libgl-gst` `libgl1-mesa-*` so I am quite lost at the moment.

**EDIT**

To be precise it is an older version of OpenCV: it is the 2.4.13.6.

The lines initializing VideoCapture are the following (I reported only the relevant ones):

```
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    string devId;

    VideoCapture capture;

    if(argc>4)
    {
         int captureNumber;
         string deviceId=argv[1];

         captureNumber=atoi(argv[1]);
         capture.open(captureNumber);

     }
```

**EDIT 2**

On OSX the same code works without giving this exception (there were only dynamic libraries problem).

Comment: What arguments do you pass to the OpenCV VideoCapture constructor? It is good if you post a sample code, it may look irrelevant, but sometimes it helps to find the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I inserted the relevant lines

Comment: From those messages it is hard to guess what is the cause.  Post some [gstreamer debug messages](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) - maybe a debug level of 4 (info) is good

Comment: how to set level 4?